# how to work on numpy arrays during training for custom loss function

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, keras

I am currently working on a neural network implemented with tensorflow and keras, what i need to do is to call a function, that i cannot reimplement, that works on numpy arrays and not on Tensors,  My first idea was to just call .numpy like this

```
def loss_gi(y_true, y_pred): # <class 'tensorflow.python.framework.ops.Tensor'>
  x = gamma(np.squeeze(y_true.numpy() , axis=0), np.squeeze(y_pred.numpy() , axis=0)) 
  return np.nansum(x)

with strategy.scope():
  model = hd_unet_model(INPUT_SIZE)
  model.compile(optimizer=Adam(lr=0.001), 
                loss=loss_gi)
```

Where gamma returns a volume.
But during `Model.fit` if you try to call `y.numpy` on a Tensor you get the error `Tensor has no attribute numpy`, this happens because `.numpy`  works only in eager execution and not in graph execution (at least this is what i understood).

Does anybody know of a way to create a custom loss function that works on numpy arrays?

Comment: you need to work in Eager mode to achieve that.

Comment: The loss function got to be in TF so that it produces gradient. Using Numpy loss function kills the whole idea of TF library as tensors with gradients. 
1) from what I see, your y_pred and y_true come as tf.Tensors. Why not using pure TF for the custom loss function?
2) if y_trus is originally in numpy - you'd convert it into TF inside the fuction anyways. So why not just converting y_true to TF before runnign the model.

Comment: @sooobus yes you are right, but im failing to do that and im not sure how i should, i tried using tf.numpy_fuction but im not getting any result

Answer (score 0):

The loss function got to be in TF so that it produces gradient. Using Numpy loss function kills the whole idea of TF library as tensors with gradients. So your choices are:

1. using pure TF for the custom loss function.
2. if y_true is originally in numpy - converting y_true to TF before runnign the model.